# table elements are not encrypted

Tags: tls, openssl, html

I read a security book a while ago that said HTML table elements are sent plain text, even if the server connection is https. Is this accurate?

I'm thinking about making an on-line purchase from a site where the order form is in a table.

The book I think was called Hack-IT.

Comment: The book is incorrect. Table elements are part of the html document, and the whole document is encrypted with https.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could verify what the book said.

Comment: @schroeder Its missing from the Library where I got it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> HTML table elements are sent plain text, even if the server connection
>   is https.

Completely wrong. Please throw this book away.

For the HTTP server, the whole HTML file is just a file, nothing less or more. The content is irrelevant. Either the whole file is sent encrypted, or the whole file is sent as plaintext.